# Basic Bash elif / else not running

Tags: bash, shell

Could someone comment on why the elif / else part of this script will not run.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE="/etc/shadow"

if [ -e "$FILE" ] ; then
        echo "Shadow passwords enable."
elif [ -w "$FILE" ] ; then
        echo "You have permissions to the file."
else
        echo "You do not have permissions to the file."
fi
```

Tried double brackets, adjusted white space still just runs "if" part then exits.  If I redo it as two "if" statements it works fine.

I have reviewed other examples and seems like this should work.

Comment: `else` and `elif` parts are only _supposed_ to run if the `if` condition is false. Running only the first `echo` and then exiting constitutes _exactly what this code is written to do_; if you expect anything different, the question should explain _why_  something different is expected.

Comment: Your logic is simply backwards - you're checking for file permissions only in the case that the file doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you were expecting.  In an `if` / `elif` / `else` statement, the body of exactly one of those clauses will be executed (and if there is no `else` clause then it's *at most* one).  Perhaps you want instead to nest one `if` / `else` inside another?

Comment: BTW, as an aside unrelated to your immediate issue, note that all-caps names are used for variables that reflect or modify the shell's behavior during operation; you should use lowercase names for your own variables. This is a POSIX-specified convention; see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html

Comment: To fire the `elif`, you have to make the test in the `if` evaluate to _false_. Since `-e` tests the **existence** of a _directory entry_ (it does not need to be a file), the only way to make the `if`  fail would be to do a `rm /etc/shadow` before running the script; but in this case, the `elif` would of course be _false_ too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elif and else didn't run because you tested if $FILE exists (-e), and it does exist. Therefore, the tests stopped right there.

Please notice that if, else-if and else conditions will be tried until the first satisfied expression. Once one is satisfied, other expressions are ignored.

Having that said, -w check if file exists and if it is writable, so you could simply drop the -e condition and use only -w:

```bash
if [ -w "$FILE" ] ; then
        echo "You have permissions to the file."
else
        echo "You do not have permissions to the file."
fi
```

However, if you really want to test existence before write permissions, then make it a nested if:

```bash
if [ -e "$FILE" ] ; then
    echo "Shadow passwords enable."
    if [ -w "$FILE" ] ; then
        echo "You have permissions to the file."
    else
        echo "You do not have permissions to the file."
    fi
else
    echo "Shadow passwords disabled."
fi
```

Either way, I highly recommend reading [Conditional Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) and [Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) from [bash's man page](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html).